# Posso passar um resultado de um cálculo para porcentagem em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

O cálculo eu consegui fazer com o JavaScript, só que a saída dele tem que ser em porcentagem.

```
<script>
var mb = document.querySelector("input[name=medidab]");
mb.addEventListener("keyup", calcImc, false);
function calcImc(){
   var md_val = parseFloat(mb.value);
   medidab = (md_val/50*100).toFixed(1);
   if(!isNaN(medidab)){
      document.querySelector("input[name=circunferenciabraco]").value = medidab;
   }
}
</script>
```

e aqui e o formulário, eu coloco o valor em um campo e o valor do calculo já sai no outro. Só que tem que sair em porcentagem e eu não sei se é possível.

```
<div>
   <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="medidab" placeholder="Medida do Braço" maxlength="5">
</div>
<div>
   <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="circunferenciabraco" placeholder="Circunferência do Braço" maxlength="5"></br>
</div>
```

Comment: Bruno, não seria caso de fazer somente `.value = medidab + '%';`? Podes explicar melhor caso não seja isso?

Comment: Oi Bruno, viste a resposta e comentário aqui? Era isso que procuravas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você já conseguiu fazer o cálculo, basta concatenar o `%` no resultado:

```
document.querySelector("input[name=circunferenciabraco]").value = medidab+"%";
```

```js
var mb = document.querySelector("input[name=medidab]");
mb.addEventListener("keyup", calcImc, false);
function calcImc(){
   var md_val = parseFloat(mb.value);
   medidab = (md_val/50*100).toFixed(1);
   if(!isNaN(medidab)){
      document.querySelector("input[name=circunferenciabraco]").value = medidab+"%";
   }
}
```

```html
<div>
   <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="medidab" placeholder="Medida do Braço" maxlength="5">
</div>
<div>
   <input class="campo-form-c" type="text" name="circunferenciabraco" placeholder="Circunferência do Braço" maxlength="5"></br>
</div>
```